# Spark on EC2 - HDFS

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, hdfs

When I go to run a small program that takes as an argument a small dataset I get the following error:

> Input path does not exist: hdfs://ec2-52-16-229-29.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9000/user/root/file-name

I uploaded the dataset to the Master and then RYNCd it to the slaves. I have never stated I wanted the dataset in HDFS and the path it's searching is not the path I passed as an argument!

I'm assuming, as I'm not using S3 or some other external data source, that HDFS must be used and I can't access the dataset in a local fashion on each machine. It's only a small dataset so I didn't really see a benefit of using HDFS.

How do I get the file into HDFS? And then what file path do I pass as an argument to my jar?

Comment: You don't need the file on HDFS. Spark can read stuff from the local drives on your nodes. Please show us how you were trying to open the file from within Spark (i.e. show us the code). Most likely, you need to prepend your file path with `file://` so that Spark knows to look at your local drive.

Comment: Nick, you were 100% spot on! prepending the file path with `file://user/root` works a treat. However, it would be nice to maybe test out HDFS. Any suggestions on how to get the dataset into HDFS correctly? Thanks again!

Comment: You'd have to look at the HDFS docs. Look up this command: `hadoop fs -put` That should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Nick! I've been working through the Hadoop docs and I've got the `cp` command to work to get the data into HDFS. When I use the `-copyFromLocal` command I get a `File does not exist` error. Any ideas? I'll check out `-put` now! Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that when using `-copyFromLocal` I can get it to work by prepending the file path with `$HOME/`. When I used the file path of `user/root/myItem` it says it doesn't exist - which is strange because that's the exact file path I use elsewhere with no problems. Any ideas?